# How to restrict elements in Django templates?

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-templates

template:

```
{% for c in feed.comment_set.all reversed %}
  <b>{{c.msg}}</b>
{% endfor %}
```

Question 1: Here I want only recent 3 comments to be shown. How do I limit the comments.

Question 2: How to add a 'show more' button which will load the remaining comments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin template filter [`slice`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice) that you can use to only show 3 entries of a longer list.

But as your question is tagged with jquery anyway you could probably try a plugin like [showMore](http://www.kaibakh.org/michele/showmore/#), that seems to be the exact fit for your problem.

If you want to tailor you own solution look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077045/how-to-show-more-list-using-jquery/2077123#2077123). 
Though it uses php the basic logic should be the same and adaptable to Django.